# Hide a cell in a DataGrid (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm working with a DataGrid in a xaml file in a UWP application.

I want to hide some cells conditionally. I tried doing this by setting the Visibility property of the DataGridTextColumn element with a Binding and an IValueConverter that returns Visible or Collapsed; this doesn't work. I assume it's because Visibility is not a dependency property.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: UWP doesnt have a DataGrid, you must be using a package?

Comment: You should probably hide the cell contents rather than the cell itself.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `Visibility` property is not a dependency property, **{Binding}** extension does not work. But you could use **{x:Bind}** extension to implement data binding of `Visibility` property, based on the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/dependency-properties-overview#binding-sources-binding-targets-the-role-of-frameworkelement) which says “`However, to be the target of a {Binding} markup extension or Binding, that property must be a dependency property. {x:Bind} does not have this requirement as it uses generated code to apply its binding values.`”.

Take the code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/datagrid_basics#datagridcomboboxcolumn) as an example:

1. Add a property to the `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
    ……
   public bool Visibility { get; set; }
}
```

2. Initiate `Persons` like this:

```
Persons = new List<Person>
{
    new Person
    {
        PersonId = 1, DepartmentId = 3, FirstName = "Ronald", LastName = "Rumple",
        Position = "Network Administrator",Visibility=false
    },
    ……
};
```

3. Use [DataGridTemplateColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/datagrid_basics#datagridtemplatecolumn) to add a column to do the binding of `Visibility` property:

```
<controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="header">
        <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Person">
                <Grid Visibility="{x:Bind Visibility,Mode=OneWay}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind FirstName}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    ……
</controls:DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: If your problem is resolved, it is better if you could mark the answer so that poeple with the same problems could find a solution quickly.